# Need help setting up FQDN with Dynamic IP on a Arch Linux box

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, hosts-file

I'm running Arch Linux and I'm trying to figure out what the proper way to set up my FQDN on my box. I plan to be running Nextcloud with some other stuff and I want to have my domain name properly associated with my box. The IP address is dynamic and my router is using DynamicDNS to update the domain registrar with the correct IP.  Below are the contents of hosts files I was supposed to edit.  I'm not sure if I should put my LAN IP or not. I'm also not sure what the proper way to include my WAN IP since it's dynamic. Since I also have a local LAN domain name (.lan) should that be included into the hosts file?  Can someone please help?

My /etc/hosts file looks like

```
# Static table lookup for hostnames.
# See hosts(5) for details.
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.10 foo.testsite.com  foo
```

And my /etc/hostname contains the one line

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless that box is running a DNS service then the host file is only used by that box.  So no , do not put on the wan IP since it cannot reach itself using the wan address.

Comment: So does my set up look correct?